# Unity: Access animations inside animation component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

so the 3D person in my team made a tree and the tree has an animation for each leaf, so the thing is that i need to play all the animations of the leaves at the same time, so i tried to do this by code but Unity only plays the first of them (there are 23 animations), can you help me please ? , this is my code:

```
public Animation anim;

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    foreach (AnimationState state in anim)
    {
        anim.Play();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Animation.Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Play.html)

> If no name is supplied then the default animation will be played

What you want to do is start all animations by name:

```
anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
foreach (AnimationState state in anim)
{
    anim.Play(state.name);
}
```

However also note

> Animations must be marked as ‘Legacy’ in the Inspector for the animations to be found by this method. This option appears after switching the Inspector Window to ‘Debug’.